# Set two children elements with equal width, each with 50% in wpf

Tags: wpf

If I have two elements in a stackpanel:

```
<StackPanel Margin="2,2,2,2" Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
      <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Age}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

How can I set them with the width equally 50%,50%?

Comment: Do you need to use a stackpanel for this? Why not use a grid. Seems to me thats more suitable for your 50/50 width.

Comment: it is not required to use StackPanel. how to use a Grid then?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To answer your comment

```
<Grid>
   <!-- Define Columns -->
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    

   <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
   <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Age}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thank you. This is really what I needed. Could you please also answer my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205271/using-textbox-or-checkbox-depending-on-the-type-of-an-attribue

Comment: FYI if you want to have space between the collumns use margin on one of the elements in the grid

Comment: How to do define text block to occupy 100 %

Answer (score 19):

use UnformGrid with columns 2 or Grid with 2 columns

```
<UniformGrid Columns="2">
     <TextBox></TextBox>
     <TextBox></TextBox>
</UniformGrid>
```

or

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
               Text="{Binding Name}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
             Text="{Binding Age}" />

</Grid>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. The UniformGrid is genius. I am sorry. The other person answered for the question first. Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you have an idea for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205271/using-textbox-or-checkbox-depending-on-the-type-of-an-attribue