# Using either checkbox or textbox for an enum type

Tags: c#, wpf

If I have this structure:

```
public class Parent
{
  public string Name{get; set;}
  public List<Child> Childs {get; set;}
}

public class Child
{
  public string Name{get; set;}
  public string Value{get; set;}
  public enum ValueType {get; set;}
}

public enum ValueType
{
    Int,
    Boolean,
    String
};

public class ParentFactory
{
   public List<Parent> Parents {get; set;}

   public ParentFactory()
   {
      Child child1 = new Child() {Name="Filter1", Value="1", ValueType=ValueType.String};
      Child child2 = new Child() {Name="isExecuted", Value="true", ValueType=ValueType.Boolean};
      Child child3 = new Child() {Name="Width", Value="10", ValueType=ValueType.Int};

      Parent parent1 = new Parent(){Name="Adam", Childs = new List<Child>(){child1, child2}};
      Parent parent2 = new Parent(){Name="Kevin", Childs = new List<Child>(){child3}};

      Parents = new List<Parent>(){parent1, parent2};
   }
}
```

I want to bind the object: `ParentFactory parentFactory = new ParentFactory()` to ItemsControl:

```
<DockPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Parents}">
    </ItemsControl>
</DockPanel>

 <Window.Resources>
     <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Parent}">
         <StackPanel Margin="2,2,2,1">
              <Expander Header="{Binding Name}">
                  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}" />
              </Expander>
         </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Child}">
            <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding ValueType}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
 </Window.Resources>
```

In the Stackpanel, there are one control: TextBox. However, I want it to be more dynamic: if the ValueType is a Boolean then use a Checkbox and else use a Textbox for the: `<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value}"/>`.

Is this possible, and if so, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Didnt you just ask a similar question fr check box or text box based on marital status? Y dont you u use enum value for the data template trigger? it will work just fine.

Comment: @Dzire yes, I just have added another question. this one is different of using an enum. The second one: <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value}"/> should be either a Checkbox or Textbox depending on the value of the ValueType.

Comment: @Dzire I just have updated my question. I believe that it should be different.

Comment: @devn Use the solution that i gave write 2 more DataTrigrers for the `EnumType` same as for boolean it should work

Comment: @devn yes, datz wat i was saying. use data triggers :) Thanks adcool2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do it is to have both of them in your panel and define two new boolean properties that will control their `Visibility` through a Boolean To Visibility `ValueConverter`.

```
public bool IsValueTypeBoolean
{
    get
    {
         ...Conditions that will return true for CheckBox.
    }
}

public bool IsValueTypeOther
{
    get
    {
         return !this.IsValueBoolean;
    }
}

<TextBox Grid.Column="2" Visibility="{Binding IsValueTypeOther, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"/> 
<CheckBox Grid.Column="2" Visibility="{Binding IsValueTypeBoolean, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Boolean To VisibilityConverter

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(Visibility))]
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool myValue = (bool)value;

        if (myValue)
            return Visibility.Visible;
        else
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Add this as a resource to your XAML:

```
 <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter"></local:VisibilityConverter>
```

I hope there are no typos...

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `DataTemplate` dynamically

## Xaml

```
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate x:Key="Condition1">
                           <TextBox></TextBox> // Do you binding
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:Key="Condition2">
                           <CheckBox></CheckBox> // Do you binding
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataTemplate.Resources>                    
                </DataTemplate>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentField"
                                      Content="{Binding}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Condition1}" /> 
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ValueType}" Value="1">
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentField" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Condition2}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

Be sure to set the Bindings correctly ... and make the `DataTemplates` for `Condition1` and `Condition2`

hope it helps :)

Comment: @devn Solution for this one is also same no need to add more DataTriggers but if you enum increases or you want to display a particuar control you each type.. just add more DataTriggers there...

Comment: 2007, I have spent an hour of how to use this but I could not make it work. COuld you please provide a full answer corresponding to my question? thanks in advance

Comment: could you please provide a full answer to my question? I kept searching for it but I could not make it work yet. thanks in advance.